# Missing dependencies, unmet peer dependency in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I just wanted to add background geolocation to my Ionic 2 app running:

```
 npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation
```

I get the error:

```
> ├── @ionic-native/background-geolocation@3.5.0  ├── UNMET PEER
> DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@^3.1.0 └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY
> rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
> 
> npm WARN @ionic-native/background-geolocation@3.5.0 requires a peer of
> @ionic-native/core@^3.1.0 but none was installed. npm WARN
> @ionic-native/background-geolocation@3.5.0 requires a peer of
> rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "App2: An Ionic project"
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Peer dependency is a warning only, it wont break your build, the peer dependencies you need are `@ionic-native/core@^3.1.0` and `rxjs@^5.0.1`

I see you have `"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12"` change it to `"rxjs": "^5.0.1"`

as for `@ionic-native/core` i see you have `"@ionic-native/core": "^3.5.0"` and its a later version that the peer dependency needs.. probably would be fine as is.